# Can't move animation image vertical correct with @keyframe

Tags: html, css, animation

I using a vertical sprite sheet in an animation with `@keyframe`.

I just can't get it to work correctly.

```css
body{
  background: brown;
}
.hi {
    width: 117px;
    height: 180px;

    background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/DxApxaV.png");
    
    -webkit-animation: play .9s steps(8) infinite;
       -moz-animation: play .9s steps(8) infinite;
        -ms-animation: play .9s steps(8) infinite;
         -o-animation: play .9s steps(8) infinite;
            animation: play .9s steps(8) infinite;
}
@keyframes play {
   from { background-position:0px; }
     to { background-position:0px 1080px; }
}
```

```html
<div class="hi"></div>
```

I tried using `@keyframe` with `background-position-y` axis to no avail.
It should be animation at 1 frame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just needed to change the steps to 6.

Basically speaking, `steps` is the number of sprites you are wanting to show over X time. So in this case, you only have 6, not 9.

I also changed it to use `background-position.y`.. note that having `background-position: 0 0;`  is also good practice for when you come across more complex, grid sprite sheets.

```css
body{
  background: brown;
}
.hi {
    width: 117px;
    height: 180px;

    background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/DxApxaV.png");
    background-position: 0 0;        

    -webkit-animation: play .9s steps(6) infinite;
       -moz-animation: play .9s steps(6) infinite;
        -ms-animation: play .9s steps(6) infinite;
         -o-animation: play .9s steps(6) infinite;
            animation: play .9s steps(6) infinite;
}
@keyframes play {
   from { background-position-y:0px; }
     to { background-position-y:1080px; }
}
```

```html
<div class="hi"></div>
```

Comment: ... and set `y` axis to 0px. `from { background-position:0px 0px; }`. Thanks.

Comment: Well actually I just changed it to use `background-position-y` so you can see how to do that as well.